# How to Insert a DataTable containing Null values in to Sql Server Table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, datatable

I have a DataTable which also contains some Null values such as

```
   ID             CustomerID           CompanyID
 -------        --------------       --------------
   1                  2                  Null
   2                 Null                1
   3                  5                  4
```

I want to insert this DataTable into a Table. 
In SQL Server 2005, I have one Table called "JobDetails" which has three columns "JobOrderID", "CustomerID" and "CompanyID". So the above DataTable to be inserted into the "JobDetails" table like follows:

```
   JobOrderID      CustomerID          CompanyID
  ------------    ------------        ------------
       1               2                Null
       2              Null                1
       3               5                  4
```

How to achieve this? I tried to pass the DataTable as XML. But due to the presence of NUll values it throws error not inserting.

Error means,  the XML tags not considering the NULL values, so it takes as

```
  <NewDataSet>
      <JobDetails> 
          <JobOrderID>1</JobOrderID>
          <CustomerID>2</CustomerID>
      </JobDetails>
      <JobDetails> 
          <JobOrderID>2</JobOrderID>
          <CompanyID>1</CompanyID>
      </JobDetails>
      <JobDetails> 
          <JobOrderID>3</JobOrderID>
          <CustomerID>5</CustomerID>
          <CompanyID>4</CompanyID>
      </JobDetails>
  </NewDataSet>
```

It neglects the tags which contains NULL. So the insertion not takes place.

Comment: What does the thrown error say?

Comment: @Akram: I edited my Question. Please look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you would insert from a `DataTable` via an *adapter* (such as `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter`). This will handle the nulls etc. You could also use `SqlBulkCopy` if it is very large (although you need to be careful about transaction logs etc in that case, as a bulk insert might not be fully logged, IIRC).

caveat: personally, I would be using a `DataTable` here *anyway* - I'd be using regular typed classes.

Answer (score 1):

In a case to get a DataTable into another table, use the SqlBulkCopy class. Ensure your values that are null are set to DBNull.Value as opposed to 'null' and use the SqlBulkCopy to set the destination table name

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
{
   bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = destinationTableName;
   bulkCopy.WriteToServer(yourDataTable);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier if you follow the method described in the following article:

[Use DataTable to update table in Database](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Database-ADO.net/UseDataTabletoupdatetableinDatabase.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can replace `NULL` with their default value for ex. in companyId field `NULL` replace with -1 or 0 and in SQL Server you can again replace -1 or o to `NULL`.

Through replacing ID will be part of `XML`. **I know it is not good solution.**